# How to Export Each Grouped Table in a List of Tables to a Different Excel Tab Using ReadXL and Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)
library(readxl)
```

Using the gss_cat dataset from the forcats package I created a grouped and summarized dataframe then split the data by the marital and race variables (If there's a better tidyverse method than using lapply here that would be a great bonus).

```
Survey<-gss_cat%>%
select(marital,race,relig,denom)%>%
group_by(marital,race,relig,denom)%>%
summarise(Count=n())%>%
mutate(Perc=paste0(round(100*Count/sum(Count),2),"%"))%>%
drop_na()

Survey%>%split(.$marital)%>%
lapply(function(x) split(x,x$race))
```

However I'm stuck trying to export the final list to an Excel file with readxl. More specifically, I want to export select tables in the list to separate Excel tabs. For example, divided by race, so that each race category is on a different tab in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `readxl` does not write Excel files.  See [the thread for issue 231](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/231) on the readxl GitHub page.  It looks like the [`writexl`](https://github.com/ropensci/writexl) package (not [yet] part of the tidyverse) is recommended instead.

Second, `split()` can take a list as an argument.

```
list_of_dfs <- survey %>% split(list(.$marital, .$race), sep='_')
```

Putting it together, assuming you've installed `writexl`:

```
require(tidyverse) 
require(forcats)
require(writexl)

survey <- 
    gss_cat %>%
        select(marital, race, relig, denom) %>%
        group_by(marital, race, relig, denom) %>%
        summarise(Count=n()) %>%
        mutate(Perc=paste0(round(100*Count/sum(Count), 2), "%")) %>%
        drop_na()

list_of_dfs <- survey %>% split(list(.$marital, .$race), sep='_')

write_xlsx(list_of_dfs, 'out.xlsx')
```

Note that there are no checks on the suitability of the names of the worksheets that `write_xlsx` tries to create.  If your data contained illegal characters in the `marital` or `race` column, or if you used an illegal character in the `sep` argument to `split()`, then the operation would fail.  (Try using `sep = ':'` if you don't believe me.)